# Can I compare screen regions to reference images in UI Automation scripts?

Tags: ios, ui-automation

In a UI Automation script, is it possible to save part or all of the screen to a file to compare it to a reference image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UIATarget has a method captureScreenWithName that takes a screen shot of device screen or captureRectWithName that captures only given rect. Image is saved in log and can be accessed from instruments report.

After taking a screenshot you can use imagemagick command line tools with UIAHost method 
performTaskWithPathArgumentsTimeout to compare screenshot with reference one during test or do comparison later after all tests are done...